# How do I write a text file to Google Cloud Storage from JavaScript bound to a Google Sheet?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-cloud-storage

Awhile ago, I created a Google Sheet with bound JavaScript that assembles email text from the Google Sheet content, saves the text to a Google drive as an html file, and then sends the html as the body of the email with a link to the html page labeled "view as html"

When Google stopped allowing Google drive to host html pages, I created a Zapier trigger to copy the pages to DropBox. Now DropBox also no longer supports the hosting of html pages.

I understand from the documentation that Google Cloud Storage will host html pages. I have not yet found a way to write a text file from JavaScript bound to a Google Sheet to Google Cloud Storage.

Here is a snippet of the code I am using now. I would like to replace the first statement, that writes the text file to Google Drive, with code that writes the file to Google Cloud Storage.

```
  var outFile = DriveApp.getFolderById('0B4Oo7-sRYcsLRlp1V056a21CNEk').createFile(String(String(Number(dtNow))) + ".html", stBdy)  

  stBdy = stBdy.replace('<p align="right">webpage view</p>','<p align="right"><a href="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18189100/' + String(Number(dtNow)) +'.html" target="_blank">View As Webpage</a></p>');

  GmailApp.sendEmail(stTo, stSbj, stBdy, {replyTo: stReply, htmlBody: stBdy});
```

Comment: UPDATE: Bruce McPherson's library works like a charm. Thanks Bruce fire writing it and thanks Spencer for recommending it.

Comment: Since saving a file with mine type "text/html" is not one of Bruce's examples, I will add for the benefit of those post on a Google search... To have your JavaScript save a file to google cloud storage as "text/html", convert your text to a Blob object of type "text/html" before you pass it to the gsc library routines.

Answer (score 1):

Bruce Mcpherson has written a solid GCS library with a indepth write up. You can find it at:
http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/googlecloud/gcsstore